# Extract characters from a LONG in Oracle 19c

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle19c

I have a table t with a column c which is of type LONG. I want to extract the last 100 characters.

The difficulties are:

1. The string functions don’t work with LONGs.
2. It’s hard to convert a LONG to a CLOB, even to_lob and cast seem to fail
3. The values may exceed the length of a VARCHAR.

I have tried the most obvious solutions:

```
select right(to_lob(c), 100) from t
```

which fails with

> inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG

and with a CTE

```
with foo as (
  select cast(to_lob(c) as clob) c
)
select substr(c, length(c)-99, 100) ending
from foo
```

which gives the same error.

Comment: Read through https://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430 (if you have not done so already).

Answer (score 0):

If your long values are < 32KB in size, you can simply assign them to a local `varchar2` variable in PL/SQL. It's particularly easy if they are less than 4KB, as then we can return a `varchar2` accessible to SQL. Here's how it might look:

```
CREATE TYPE foo_rowtype IS OBJECT (long_col1 varchar2(4000), col2 int, col3 varchar2(5)); -- all the columns needed from the table
CREATE TYPE foo_tabtype IS TABLE OF foo_rowtype;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo2string
  RETURN foo_tabtype PIPELINED
AS
  var_string varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR rec_row IN (SELECT *
                    FROM foo)
  LOOP
    var_string := rec_row.long_col1; -- long to varchar2 conversion here
    PIPE ROW(foo_rowtype(SUBSTR(var_string,1,4000),rec_row.col2,rec_row.col3));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

-- now query it normally, in this case getting the last 100 chars:
 SELECT SUBSTR(long_col1,LENGTH(long_col1)-100)),col2,col3
  FROM foo2string

-- older versions may require the TABLE operator:

SELECT SUBSTR(long_col1,LENGTH(long_col1)-100)),col2,col3
  FROM TABLE(foo2string)
```

If the values are greater than 4KB you'd need to have the function itself get the end of the string. And if they are more than 32KB, then you'd have to use a much more complex method involving `dbms_sql` to progressively read the long with iterated `dbms_sql.column_value_long` calls and appends to a temporary CLOB. Far more complex. This is why we never use the long datatype. About the only place it should be found is in Oracle's data dictionary in some views, and the above technique can be used to make those views manageable by code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(LIST_OF_COLUMNS_LEADING_TO_UNIQUE_ROW, c, 'text()').getclob(),4000,1) as c
from foo ;
```

If you have a PK in your table the LIST_OF_COLUMNS_LEADING_TO_UNIQUE_ROW is trivial.

Example:

```
select index_name, column_position, dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(index_owner, index_name, column_position, column_expression, 'text()').getclob(),4000,1) as ce
from all_ind_expressions ;
```